# Create JSON object by manipulating existing JSON object using Javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I've a JSON object, in which I'm manipulating the data and trying to construct a new JSON object. The issue is I'm not able to find out the create a dynamic part of JSON object. Here is the actual JSON object

```
[{"acptFlag":true,"count":14288,"limsFlag":true,"plantId":30,"plantName":"Camilla, GA","supplierId":20,"supplierName":"Keystone Foods"},{"acptFlag":false,"count":344,"limsFlag":true,"plantId":30,"plantName":"Camilla, GA","supplierId":20,"supplierName":"Keystone Foods"},{"acptFlag":false,"count":700,"limsFlag":true,"plantId":31,"plantName":"Albany, KY","supplierId":20,"supplierName":"Keystone Foods"},{"acptFlag":true,"count":9500,"limsFlag":true,"plantId":31,"plantName":"Albany, KY","supplierId":20,"supplierName":"Keystone Foods"},{"acptFlag":false,"count":227,"limsFlag":true,"plantId":32,"plantName":"Green Forest, AR","supplierId":21,"supplierName":"Tyson Foods"},{"acptFlag":true,"count":7049,"limsFlag":true,"plantId":32,"plantName":"Green Forest, AR","supplierId":21,"supplierName":"Tyson Foods"},{"acptFlag":true,"count":10742,"limsFlag":true,"plantId":33,"plantName":"Dawson, GA","supplierId":21,"supplierName":"Tyson Foods"},{"acptFlag":false,"count":506,"limsFlag":true,"plantId":33,"plantName":"Dawson, GA","supplierId":21,"supplierName":"Tyson Foods"}]
```

The required JSON object is

```
[{"supplierName":"Keystone Foods","1":(344/(344+14288)) , "2":700/(700+9500))}},{"supplierName":"Tyson Foods"","1":(227/(227+7049)) , "2":(506/(506+10742))}}]
```

Here I'm trying to put "Keystone Foods" data in a single object. `"1":(344/(344+14288)) , "2":700/(700+9500))` represents the false count/ true count. "`1`" and "`2`" represent the count of Plant. I got stuck up in constructing the plant count code.

Here is my existing code.

```
var resultJSON = {}, arr = [];
var jsonObj = JSON.parse(obj)
for (var key in jsonObj) {
  if (jsonObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
    var val = jsonObj[key];
    var supplierName = val.supplierName;
    arr.push(supplierName);    
  }
}
var M = {}, R = []
getUniqueSuppliers(arr)
function getUniqueSuppliers(arr) {
   for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      M[arr[i]] = "supplierName"
   }
  for(var i in M) {
    R.push(i)
  }
}
checkEachSupplier(R)
function checkEachSupplier(R) { 
    for (var index = 0; index < R.length; index++) {
       var supplierName = R[index]
       createNewJSON(supplierName)
   }
}
getPlantTotalValueBasedOnSupplier(R);
function createNewJSON(supplierName) {

    for (var key in jsonObj) {
       if (jsonObj.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
       var val = jsonObj[key];    
       if(supplierName == val.supplierName) {       
         resultJSON[supplierName] = {"supplierName" : supplierName}
       }
     }
   }
 }
 console.log(resultJSON)
```

My JSON fiddle :
https://jsfiddle.net/7u5qphx9/6/

Comment: @charlietfl, it means "Keystone plants" has two varieties of plants. 1 means 1st plant, 2 means 2nd plant

Comment: @NinaScholz, what error quote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe this helps.

It uses a temporary object `temp` for the `count`.

```
{
    "Keystone Foods": {
        "30": {
            "true": 14288,
            "false": 344
        },
        "31": {
            "false": 700,
            "true": 9500
        }
    },
    "Tyson Foods": {
        "32": {
            "false": 227,
            "true": 7049
        },
        "33": {
            "true": 10742,
            "false": 506
        }
    }
}
```

The code in parts:

```
temp = obj1.reduce(function (r, a) {
    // ...
    return r;
}, {}),
```

This [`Array.prototype.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) iterates over `obj1` and takes an empty object as a start value. The callback function returns the object `r` for the next iteration step or at the end as result.

```
r[a.supplierName] = r[a.supplierName] || {};
```

A short writing for *if there is some value of `r[a.supplierName]`, than take  `r[a.supplierName]`, otherwise make a new object*.

> ```
> {
>     "Keystone Foods": {}
> }
> ```

```
r[a.supplierName][a.plantId] = r[a.supplierName][a.plantId] || {};
```

It is the same here for the property `plantID`. A new object is created if there is no value.

> ```
> {
>     "Keystone Foods": {
>         "30": {}
>     }
> }
> ```

```
r[a.supplierName][a.plantId][a.acptFlag] = a.count;
```

This assigns the `count` to the property of the value of `a.acptFlag`.

> ```
> {
>     "Keystone Foods": {
>         "30": {
>             "true": 14288
>     },
> }
> ```

That's for the object. And now I take a look to the part for the building of a new array with the wanted objects `o`.

```
obj2 = Object.keys(temp).map(function (k) {
    // ...
    return o;
});
```

First get all [keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) from `temp` and iterate over it with [`Array.prototype.map()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), because this should build a new array.

Inside the callback function

```
var o = { supplierName: k };
```

build a new object with a property `supplierName` and the value of the actual key.

```
Object.keys(temp[k]).forEach(function (kk, i) {
    // ...
});
```

Now there is to iterate over the next level of keys for the plantId.

```
o[i + 1] = '' + temp[k][kk].false + ' / (' + temp[k][kk].false + ' + ' + temp[k][kk].true + ')';
```

For every plantID, a new property is made with the the values of the true and false properties. The assigned value is a string. (It could be a number, if the line is changed to `o[i + 1] = temp[k][kk].false / (temp[k][kk].false + temp[k][kk].true);`).

```js
var obj1 = [{ "acptFlag": true, "count": 14288, "limsFlag": true, "plantId": 30, "plantName": "Camilla, GA", "supplierId": 20, "supplierName": "Keystone Foods" }, { "acptFlag": false, "count": 344, "limsFlag": true, "plantId": 30, "plantName": "Camilla, GA", "supplierId": 20, "supplierName": "Keystone Foods" }, { "acptFlag": false, "count": 700, "limsFlag": true, "plantId": 31, "plantName": "Albany, KY", "supplierId": 20, "supplierName": "Keystone Foods" }, { "acptFlag": true, "count": 9500, "limsFlag": true, "plantId": 31, "plantName": "Albany, KY", "supplierId": 20, "supplierName": "Keystone Foods" }, { "acptFlag": false, "count": 227, "limsFlag": true, "plantId": 32, "plantName": "Green Forest, AR", "supplierId": 21, "supplierName": "Tyson Foods" }, { "acptFlag": true, "count": 7049, "limsFlag": true, "plantId": 32, "plantName": "Green Forest, AR", "supplierId": 21, "supplierName": "Tyson Foods" }, { "acptFlag": true, "count": 10742, "limsFlag": true, "plantId": 33, "plantName": "Dawson, GA", "supplierId": 21, "supplierName": "Tyson Foods" }, { "acptFlag": false, "count": 506, "limsFlag": true, "plantId": 33, "plantName": "Dawson, GA", "supplierId": 21, "supplierName": "Tyson Foods" }],
    temp = obj1.reduce(function (r, a) {
        r[a.supplierName] = r[a.supplierName] || {};
        r[a.supplierName][a.plantId] = r[a.supplierName][a.plantId] || {};
        r[a.supplierName][a.plantId][a.acptFlag] = a.count;
        return r;
    }, {}),
    obj2 = Object.keys(temp).map(function (k) {
        var o = { supplierName: k };
        Object.keys(temp[k]).forEach(function (kk, i) {
            o[i + 1] = '' + temp[k][kk].false + ' / (' + temp[k][kk].false + ' + ' + temp[k][kk].true + ')';
        });
        return o;
    });

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(temp, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(obj2, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```

Comment: "1 & 2" results are wrong. For 1st, it should display the falseCount/falseCount+ trueCount(Eg. "1":(344/(344+14288))

Comment: Awesome. But, I find that its a bit complex code to digest :). Can you please check for a simple one?

Comment: what do you mean with "simple one"?

Comment: Can you please check this one ? https://jsfiddle.net/7u5qphx9/6/. I mean your code is fantastic. But, I haven't much used keys & map till now. Anything can be updated to my fiddle?

Comment: Also, what does this mean (obj2, 0, 4)

Comment: Can you please check my fiddle and anything can be done to that code? Because I feel your code is a complex for me :)

Comment: Are you there? Did you check my fiddle?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/101866/discussion-between-nina-scholz-and-syed).

Comment: I can't chat from here. Don't have access from here.

Comment: I really appreciate this one. But, I'm not able to understand the flow.

Comment: Awesome. Thanks a ton!. I will go through it.

Comment: But, why this is used  0, 4 in JSON.stringify(obj2, 0, 4)

Comment: please look here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_space_argument